# Django: invalid form

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and is currently trying to make a user registration form for my application. Does anyone know why *form.is_valid()* is returning False?

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']
```

views.py

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():         
            print "valid"
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)

            user = authenticate(username=username, passsword=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/admin')

        else:
            # return a blank form
            print "invalid"
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

register.html

```
<div class="container ">
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
    <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No, how could we possibly know that? Why don't you look at what form.errors says?

Comment: Make this change: `email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput)`. EmailInput is in particular a widget of EmailField.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm getting "This field is required" for username, email, and password even though I put values in each field.

Comment: You need to show your template then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any of your HTML input elements a `name` attribute. Without that, the browser can't send any data to the server.

Note that if you had used Django itself to produce the fields, they would not only include the name, but would also be populated when the invalid form was redisplayed.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you defined the form in the view, but you are not using it inside the template (register.html). I would have done something more like this:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Also, if you haven't noticed, your "return render(...)" line is within the else block. And while not necessary, I think it's good practice to define context as a dict and pass it in using context=context in the view or whatever you name it. However, for the case you have here, I'd suggest using a class-based view. It's much cleaner for signing a user up.

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class Registration(CreateView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    # in the urls.py, set name='login' for the login page
    # signing a user up will not grant admin priveleges, that is only done through the 
    # creation of a super user or if you coded your model to do so (not recommended)
```

and as for any validation, look into creating a clean(self) method inside the forms.py Like this:

```
# this will be on the same block as class Meta you defined 
# ensures no other user has the username with a different case
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    # checks if username is provided and ensures the username is not already in use 
    if username and User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
        self.add_error('username', 'A user with that username already exists.')
    
    # checks if email is provided and ensures this email is not already in use 
    if email and User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
        self.add_error('email', 'That email address is already in use.')

    return cleaned_data
```

I saw that you were setting some labels in your template, this can be done within the forms.py on the same block as the class Meta and def clean(self) I just provided:

```
# method to overwrite the form label names

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
    self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

I have not tested this, I'm going off of memory but I think this is a route similar to your use case, and it's utilizing the Django resources available to you :) Good Luck and I hope this helps!

P.S: You should look into django-crispy-forms since you're using bootstrap.